# Strange gradle issue

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build

I'd like to add the barteksc pdf dependencie but when I build my project it throw me this issue :

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

The dependencie:
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

I haven't been able to find any solution exept the offline toggle but in my case it doesn't change anything..
How can I make this work?

Edit:

Here's is my build.gradle settings:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "samere"
include ':app'
```

And here my gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.frd.samere"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'

}
```

Comment: Please add the build.gradle file.

Comment: You might want to find a different library to use. This one hasn't been updated in 3 years. It looks abandoned by the creator.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking fot it but it seems complicated, it was the main

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **jcenter()**
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer#installation

> Library is available in jcenter repository, probably it'll be in Maven Central soon.

Comment: Unfortunalty Jcenter doesn't exist anymore... But I noticed when i try an older version like :

implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.6.0' , android studio tell me to update the dependencies to the last beta, so it is well detected

Comment: @BamBou Looks like there is a similar open issue on this as well already: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/1067

Comment: Oh ok maybe it's a recent problem, do you know a good alternative to this pdf reader?

Comment: @BamBou I am not sure what would fit your needs but try searching.. for sure there are alternatives.

Comment: Jcenter still exists, but it's in read-only mode. JFrog committed to keeping it up indefinitely.